# File Create Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have this data set ( txt).
For example:

input:
0   275,276,45,278
1   442,22,455,0,456,457,458
75  62,263,264,265,266,267
80  0,516,294,517,518,519

I would like as output

output:
0 275
0 276
0 45
...
1 442
1 22
...
80 0

I use unix terminal. Let me know if you have some ideas. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how the connection "80 454", it is not mentioned in any of the second column's.

Comment: sorry for this impression, it is was not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the last part you mentioned "80 454", I found a solution to print as required.

Suppose all these values are stored in a file names "stack.txt", the following bash code will be useful.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i;do
        f=$(awk -F" " '{print $1}' <<< $i)
        line=$(cut -d" " -f2 <<<$i)
        for m in $(echo $line | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
                echo $f" "$m
        done
        echo "..."
done<stack.txt
```

Output will be

```
0 275
0 276
0 277
0 278
0 279
0 280
0 281
0 282
0 283
...
1 442
1 22
1 455
1 0
1 456
1 457
1 458
...
75 62
75 263
75 264
75 265
75 266
75 267
...
80 0
80 516
80 294
80 517
80 518
80 519
...
```

Comment: thanks you and what i need to creat a file new with this result ?

Comment: suppose the script is saved as "script.sh". you can run "bash script.sh > newfile.txt", to save the result to new file.

Comment: where i need to add this in the code that you write ?

Comment: You can add this code to the directory where the data set txt file is saved and in the code you can rename "stack.txt" with the data set txt file name.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `perl` one-liner:

```bash
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for split /,/, $F[1]' input.txt
```

Comment: thanks you and what i need to creat a file new with this result ?

Comment: Just use normal shell output redirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,n,g}awk 'gsub(",",RS $!_ FS)^_'

0 275
0 276
0 277
0 278
0 279
0 280
0 281
0 282
0 283
1 442
1 22
1 455
1 0
1 456
1 457
1 458
75 62
75 263
75 264
75 265
75 266
75 267
80 0
80 516
80 294
80 517
80 518
80 519
```